# Switch statement in jQuery not working

Tags: jquery, switch-statement

I was writing a little jQuery function that changes the value of a form field when the user changes the value of a drop down list.

My function for changing the data works but for some reason it is not "switching". Can anyone shed some light?

Here is the code:

```
$('#linktype').change(function(){
var thisType = $('#linktype').val();
switch(thisType){
    case 'facebook': 
    changeURL("http://facebook.com/");
    break;
    case 'twitter':
    changeURL("http://twitter.com/");
    break;
}
});
function changeURL(value){
$('input[id="link"]').val(value) ;  
};
```

Comment: .val() returns a string. So your cases should also be strings... Like 'facebook'

Comment: Didn't this code throw any errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`facebook` should be a string literal like `'facebook'`

```
$('#linktype').change(function(){
var thisType = $('#linktype').val();
   switch(thisType){
   case 'facebook':
```

Else you need to have a variable called `facebook` with the string value

```
var facebook = 'facebook'
$('#linktype').change(function(){
var thisType = $('#linktype').val();
   switch(thisType){
   case 'facebook':
```

Answer (score 0):

The `case` specifiers in a switch statement should not be variables, they need to be literal strings or actual values.  In your case I expect you have simply missed out the quotes around facebook.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
switch($('#linktype').val()) {
        case 'facebook':
          // do something
            break;
        case 'twitter':
          // do something
            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$('#linktype').change(function(){
var thisType = $('#linktype').val();
   switch(thisType){
   case 'facebook':
```